# Incorrect elasticsearch behavior

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, couchbase, nosql

I am new with elastic and have some questions about and strange behaviors with it.

So I'm using Couchbase database and connect it with elastic (v. 1.5.2) through [elasticsearch-transport-couchbase plugin](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase). Now I faced with the problem that some of documents doesn't update in elastic which I updated in couchbase. Also I see that aggregations are working incorrect with those documents. The mapping for those documents looks ok. The logs in elastic doesn't show anything. So does anyone have ideas what going on there? What is the source of this problem? Where can I find the answer?

PS: Creating the new replications is working for enabling changes made in database.

Comment: I don't know the plugin you mention, so this is very vague for me. But depending on how said plugin updates the documents in the index, maybe the index needs to be refreshed. Check `index.refresh_interval` for the behaviour. As for aggregations, it is important to know that these are by default approximations, since they are calculated on each shard independently. This is for performance reasons. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html shows a nice example.

Comment: All other documents refresh well. It's a plugin for creating replications to index.

Comment: Could you upload the ElasticSearch and Couchbase XDCR logs somewhere and post them (sanitize as necessary, of course)? Also, did you configure any filters in the plugin? Are the missing documents JSON or binary/counter/string?